# Compiling x64 EMMS with Visual Studio 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly

I need to execute the `EMMS` or `_mm_empty` instruction in my 64 bit application compiled using Visual Studio 2010.

Is this possible?

In 64 bit mode `_mm_empty` is unresolved, and inline assembly is not supported.

Comment: I suppose you could assemble it separately and then link it in.. a bit lame that something like that would be needed IMO

Answer (score 1):

This refers to MMX instructions which are not supported on 64-bit Windows.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ays9ef83.aspx

**MMX intrinsics use the __m64 data type, which is not supported on x64 processors.**

Comment: MMX instruction are suppored on 64-bit windows, however the __m64 data type is not supported in VS2010 for x64 builds, which doesn't mean that you cannot execute mmx instruction on windows.